# jquery image fade animate() and multiple mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

Fairly new to JavaScript and very new to jQuery. Can someone have a look at the following code and see where I am going wrong.

This is the main part of the jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("hover", ".crrightcontainer img", function() { /* trigger event on hover on an img in class crrightcontainer */
    var src = $(this).attr('src'); // get full path and filename from thumbnail
    var index = src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1; // get index to last occurrenace of file path delimiter "/"
    var fullsizeimgname = src.substr(index); // get actual filename only i.e. "cs1.jpg"
    fullsizeimgname = "/painted/fp-images/" + fullsizeimgname; // add path to give full path to the full sized image.
    $('.crleftcontainer img').animate({opacity: 0.0},1000); // fade out old full size image
    $('.crleftcontainer img').attr("src",fullsizeimgname).animate({opacity: 1.0},1000); // set full size image in browser and fade in
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deanflyer/CfxyJ/1

It works, it just seems to fire off multiple mouse events. Just move the mouse a few times over the thumbnail images and youll see what I mean, giving multiple fades.

I've tried using .stop() on the main image with animate() but this just stops everything.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this your requirement try this: http://jsfiddle.net/CfxyJ/13/

```
    $('.crrightcontainer img').css('opacity', 0.7); 

$('.crrightcontainer img').mouseenter(function () { 
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 600);
    var src = $(this).attr('src'); 
    var index = src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1; 
    var fullsizeimgname = src.substr(index);
    fullsizeimgname = "http://thepaintedtree.co.uk/fp-images/" + fullsizeimgname;  
    $('.crleftcontainer img').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('.crleftcontainer img').attr("src", fullsizeimgname).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('.crrightcontainer img').mouseleave(function () { //fadeout
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.7
    }, 600);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it seems to be only fading in now. I tried a similar thing using by chaining to .stop() but this had the same effect as your code.

Comment: @DeanDunn i have updated the fiddle and the answer. `It seems that you want to fadeOut first image` then `fadeIn the hovered image`.

Comment: Thnaks, this works perfectly. Still learning Javascript, I'm assuming this is a callback function  that triggers fadein, once fadeout is completed?

Comment: Just looked up the jquery fadein/fadeout docs, and see how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mouseenter` event. See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CfxyJ/25/. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, still the same issue. I originally tried mouseenter as well. Just trying moving the mouse between a couple of the thumbnails a few times then move the mouse off the thumbnails. Youll then see the queued animations firing off.

Comment: See the updated link [http://jsfiddle.net/CfxyJ/25/](http://jsfiddle.net/CfxyJ/25/)